# How to quickly configure allowed content for panelizer?

Tags: panels, configuration

I am developing a site which will have about 15 content types such as news, events, course etc. I need to configure allowed only specific content for panelizer. When I go to allowed content option there are tons of checkboxes which I have no problem in configuring. The problem is even though they have to be same for all content types (15 total) I have to manually repeat this task for about 15 different content types.

[image: way too many options for panelizer]

So is there any way this can be automated?

Comment: Would go for Javascript/Ajax.